# Spring Reactive implementation calling db multiple times

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive, imperative-programming

I a new to reactive and trying to accomplish the below task in efficient way. I  have a table having events for each user. I am trying to get latest row of each event name for a given user filtered with latest category.

```
table structure
user id , category , event name, details , insert timestamp, event text( payload of event)
```

Approach in reactive
// call 1 to Cassandra

```
Mono<Event> latestCategory = repository.findByUserId(userId).sort().next(); // sort is by insert 
timestamp;
```

//call 2 to Cassandra

```
Flux<Event> fluxEvents = repository.findByUserId(userId)
                .groupBy(Event::name) //grouping by event name
                 .flatmap(grp -> {
                 grp.sort() // sorting for each event
                 grp.next().zipWith(latestCategory) // picking latest row for each event
                 .filter(eventWithLatestCategory -> 
eventWithLatestCategory.getT1().category.equals(eventWithLatestCategory.getT2().category) //filtering by each category
.map(Tuple2::getT1)// picking latest event row for latest category
};
```

functionally every thing works fine but the problem i see DB call happening for each row in the table. In imperative programming, I could have just achieved it with one db call and then apply above logic. How can I do the same in reactive world?

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

The "lightest-touch" approach to what you have would be to just do:

```
Mono<Event> latestCategory = repository.findByUserId(userId).sort().next().cache();
```

...which means that `latestCategory` is only ever fetched once, then cached for all further subscriptions.

That's probably not the optimal solution though.

In this case, as it currently stands, you're doing the sorting in the `Flux` itself. That's not usually wise, but if you absolutely need to do that then you may as well just do:

```
repository.findByUserId(userId).sort().collectList().map(eventList -> {
    //Deal imperatively with a List<Event>
});
```

...and then have access to the list, from a single database call, which you can query randomly as necessary. You're actually *gaining*, not losing performance this way, since there's just one database call - and as a sorted `Flux` can never output anything until the entire publisher completes, there's no material difference between that and simply collecting to a list.

The vastly better way however would be to get cassandra to do the underlying sorting, then use [`switchOnFirst()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#switchOnFirst-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to zip the first element (your latest category) with every other that occurs:

```
repository.findByUserId(userId).switchOnFirst((signal, flux) ->
    flux.map(val -> Tuples.of(signal.get(), val)) //(In real-world use, check the `flux` actually has a value first)
)
//...etc
```

This means that:

- You only need a single database query;
- You can reactively deal with each value as it appears, without having to wait for the entire stream to end;
- No publishers need to be cached, which is best avoided if necessary.